# Disabling compass/scss source maps

Tags: compass-sass, gulp

I'm using the latest versions of sass and compass and using gulp-compass to build. I'm getting `.map` sourcemap files even though I have set `sourcemap=false` in my config.rb file and have set the option `sourcemap:false` in the gulp-compass options. I would like to disable the sourcemaps at times in order to speed up the build. It takes roughly twice the time to run the gulp task when sourcemaps are generated. Any suggestions?

config.rb:

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "img"
javascripts_dir = "js"
sourcemap = false
output_style = ":compact"
```

gulp.js:

```
gulp.task('compass', function() {
    return gulp.src(['sass/screen.scss', 'sass/screen_fallback.scss']).pipe(compass({
        config_file: 'config.rb',
        css: 'css',
        sass: 'sass',
        sourcemap: false
    })).on('error', function(err) {
        notify({
            message: err
        })
    }).pipe(notify({
        message: 'Compass processed.'
    })).pipe(minifycss()).pipe(rename({
        suffix: '.min'
    })).pipe(gulp.dest('css')).pipe(notify({
        message: 'CSS minified.'
    }));
});
```

Comment: There is currently a closed issue on this subject: https://github.com/appleboy/gulp-compass/issues/60

Comment: @DomiAlex Looks like no solution was posted. Thanks.

Comment: My "solution" is to run rimraf to delete the file after it's built. Ex: `code` gulp.task('deleteMap', ['compass'], function () {
 return gulp.src(paths.css + '/*.map', {read: false})
   .pipe(rimraf({force: true}));
}); `code` then you put this: `code` gulp.task('build', ['compass', 'deleteMap']); `code`

Comment: @DomiAlex Yes, that removes the map but the map is still created initially - which is why the compass process is slow.

Comment: I never thought this would slow compass. Interesting. You should also post this in the issue I made: https://github.com/appleboy/gulp-compass/issues/70

Answer (score 2):

You could try just running [gulp-ruby-sass](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-ruby-sass) with the `compass: true` option. Here is your task changed to use gulp-ruby-sass:

```
gulp.task('compass', function() {
    return gulp.src(['sass/screen.scss', 'sass/screen_fallback.scss']).pipe(rubysass({
        'sourcemap=none': true,
        compass: true
    })).on('error', function(err) {
        notify({
            message: err
        })
    }).pipe(notify({
        message: 'Compass processed.'
    })).pipe(minifycss()).pipe(rename({
        suffix: '.min'
    })).pipe(gulp.dest('css')).pipe(notify({
        message: 'CSS minified.'
    }));
});
```

Comment: This solved my issue. Gulp-ruby-sass was breaking when using bootstrap as it could not find the icon-font path. I had to set font_dir in config.rb, then tell gulp-ruby-sass to use compass. This fixed my particular issue.